# Modifying ASP.NET Indentity Registration to write to two different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to customize the registration for a project using ASP.NET Identity. The registration page will have the following fields:

```
UserName
Email
Password
Country 
State 
Zip
```

The UserName, Email and Password are handled by default with the **AspNetUsers** table. I know I can add columns for Country, State and Zip to the **AspNetUsers** table. But I would like to write these fields to a different table (**UserProfile**) with the **Id** as a foreign key.

So basically when a user submits a valid registration, 3 fields will write to the default **AspNetUsers** table and 3 values (along with the **Id**) with write to a custom **UserProfile** table. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your Controller (most probably `AccountController`) you have a `Register`-method which will be called with a `RegisterViewModel` parameter.

In this method, a new user gets created with something like the following (where `model` is of type `RegisterViewModel`)

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

When the creation of the new user succeeds (`result.Succeeded` is `true`), you simply create a new `UserProfile` object with the `user.Id`, `model.Country`, `model.State`, `model.Zip`, etc. and store it in your database (via your DB-context if you use Entity Framework for that).